# How to code a responsive single page application holding in one screen?

Tags: css, frameworks, single-page-application, bulma

I'm trying to code **a single page application holding inside a single screen** with the following architecture :

- One fixed header having :

  - Two columns (1/3 for left, 2/3 for right) :

    - a logo on left
    - a breadcrumb on right.
- One fixed body having :

  - Two columns (1/3 for left, 2/3 for right) :

    - a vertical container with its scroll bar:

      - one block of links
      - one block of social media links, credits, etc (that one should be always at bottom, as a footer)
    - the content container with its scroll bar

**The actual layout is showed on the following picture : https://ibb.co/2ybxxdy**

I have already tried to do it with Bulma css framework and some custom css.

```
.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
}

.no-scroll {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**Here is a JsFiddle of what I did : http://jsfiddle.net/97a6fgtp/7/**

I'm totaly open to any other framework or pure css way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try **Bootstrap** framework for the layout you have drawn.
I would suggest you try it once if you've never worked on it before.

Check it out here: [Bootstrap framework Components](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already used Bootstrap for other projects and never found a full screen component with its scroll bar.  I can't find one with your link, can you precise which component will do the job ?